# Sorting or Ordering values returned in a EF query MVC 3 vb.net app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using a where comparer in the below snippet from my function.. I need to order or sort the returned items by one of the columns... I tried using .OrderBy(function(f) f.regDate) but that dont work at all...

The part of the function in question looks like this:

```
  Function ClassFiller() As ActionResult
        Dim _courses As List(Of cours) = db.courses.ToList
        Dim _registrants As List(Of reg_info) = db.reg_info.ToList
        Dim _classSpec As List(Of classrm) = db.classrms.ToList
        Dim _CurrRegistrants As List(Of reg_classes) = db.reg_classes.ToList

  For Each Course In _courses.Where(Function(a) a.course_day = "Tuesday")
            Dim _CurrCourse As cours = Course
            Dim _classRoom As classrm = db.classrms.Where(Function(b) b.Course_ID = _CurrCourse.course_ref).FirstOrDefault()
            Dim _classmax As Integer = _classRoom.ClassMax - 1

              For Each reg In _registrants.Where(Function(d) d.tues_class1 = _CurrCourse.course_ref).OrderBy(Function(f) f.reg_date)
                Dim _ClassCount As Integer = db.reg_classes.Where(Function(c) c.tues_class = _CurrCourse.course_ref).Count
```

I need to have the _registrants ordered or sorted by a value that is in the db.reg_info under the reg_date column... Any ideas??

Comment: Could you show where you tried to put the `.OrderBy`?

Comment: Its up there in my edit now...

Comment: It looks ok -- that should give you the `registrants` where `d.tues_class1 = _CurrCourse.course_ref`, ordered by `reg_date`.  The line of code you show following the `OrderBy` doesn't use `reg`.  Is there more code below which does use `reg`?

Comment: Yes there are several more lines of code below that use the reg...

Comment: But my concern is simply ordering the list that is in the for each.. Which means I actually should use the .OrderBy up where I first declare _registrants now that I think about logically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where _registrant is declared at I should have used the following instead:

```
  Dim _registrants As List(Of reg_info) = db.reg_info.OrderBy(Function(t) t.reg_date).ToList
```

then it will already be ordered.. So the orderby is not needed in the For Each reg In _Registrants.